# Input from 4 different mice

Tags: linux, input, hardware, mouse

I need to build a simple app that takes (click only) input from 4 USB mice connected in addition to the built-in touchpad on a notebook. My preferred operating system for this setup would be Linux.

Any idea how I might be able to discern in an application which mouse a click came from? I'm open to C programming or whatever it takes. It's a simple, one-off project, so nothing too elaborate though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPX is where it's at for multiple-mouse and multitouch under Linux, but you'll need to be using xorg xserver 1.7 to get the ‘proper’ version of it; this is generally taken as part of [X11R7.5](http://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/7.5), which has only just come out as ‘stable’ and has not been integrated by the distros yet. (Even [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) doesn't have it, though that's where you'd keep an eye on if you're an Ubuntu-er.)

GTK+ seems to have had [some work](http://live.gnome.org/GTK%2B/MPX) put into allowing you to detect which mouse clicked (GdkEvent.gdk_event_get_device), but I don't know what the timetable is for getting this into a full stable release. Nor do I know how far along Qt4 is with it. So in summary the situation is: it works if you're willing to put the time into grabbing, compiling and fixing stuff, but it's not smooth with mainstream Linux, yet.

Comment: Good detailed information, though it drove me to seek a simpler solution :)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I think I found an answer to my question.

bobince's mention of xorg led me to look in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. That turns out to be full of comments like

```
# commented out by update-manager, HAL is now used
```

I had heard of HAL before, and not just in [2001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001_(film)). I tried `man -k hal` and found `lshal`, which lists 133 (!) HAL devices in my PC. In the entry for one of my mice, I found

```
linux.sysfs_path = '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/input/input6/event6'
```

which turns out to be a directory in the file system. Exploring from there, I discovered a reference back to `/dev/input/mouse3`. In fact, all my mice were sitting there in /dev/input!

Wearing my superuser cape, I was able to read /dev/input/mouse3:

```
root@carl-ubuntu:/dev/input# od -t x1 -w6 mouse3
0000000 09 00 00 08 00 00
*
```

so it turns out a left mouse click is `09 00 00 08 00 00`, consistently and repeatably.

**Conclusion:** I can read mouse clicks from /dev/input/mouseX. Having done `chmod a+r` on those files, I can even read them from a normal user account. I need to figure out a way to stop 4 mice running wild in the hands of probably drunk people from actually interacting directly with the GUI, but that's a problem for another day.

Comment: just tell X to ignore them.

/dev/input/mice is an aggregator device for all mice,.... /dev/input/mouse0 is your primary mouse,

so edit yuor xorg.conf and you're done

Comment: Heh, if only I could! There are no longer any mice (in fact, any input devices) configured in xorg.conf . But I'm not really troubled by this - I made my app cover the whole screen so it doesn't matter where the pointer is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure where to start for this, but it sounds a lot to me like it'd be similar to getting multi-touch to work.  Maybe start looking for multi-touch drivers for linux?

Also, luvieere's first link might be helpful.